# How to add unique ID to dynamically generated inputs?

Tags: jquery

Basic question; I have this code:

```
var partipiansRow = '<div class="form-row "><input type="text" id="name" class="textbox" /> <input type="text" class="textbox" id="email" /></div>'

$(".button").live("click", function(){
    $('.form-participants').after(partipiansRow);         
});
```

It creates unlimited rows with 2 inputs, how can I set them unique IDs? For example:

```
<div class="form-row "><input type="text" id="name1" class="textbox" /> <input type="text" class="textbox" id="email1" /></div>
<div class="form-row "><input type="text" id="name2" class="textbox" /> <input type="text" class="textbox" id="email2" /></div>
<div class="form-row "><input type="text" id="name3" class="textbox" /> <input type="text" class="textbox" id="email3" /></div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a counter to keep track of the ID:

```
var nextRowID = 0;

$(".button").live("click", function(){
    var id = ++nextRowID;
    var partipiansRow = '<div class="form-row "><input type="text" id="name' + id + '" class="textbox" /> <input type="text" class="textbox" id="email' + id + '" /></div>';
    $('.form-participants').after(partipiansRow);         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the current time `new Date().getTime()`

```
$(".button").live("click", function(){
    var uid           = new Date().getTime(),
        partipiansRow = '<div class="form-row' + uid + '"><input type="text" id="name' + uid + '" class="textbox" /> <input type="text" class="textbox" id="email' + uid + '" /></div>';
    $('.form-participants').after(partipiansRow);         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We can create dynamic and unique id like

```
function createId() {
  return 'xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx'.replace(/x/g, function (c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0;
    return r.toString(16);
  });
}
```

See here [Generate dynamic unique id](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaynishad/fezh4sag/)