# Assigning dynamic <div> unique ID when they are created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is related to dynamic div creation. I wanted to create an animation in which an object(bird) fly from ground to the sky (the background image-wrapper div). The bird is used as the child div of wrapper. Every time the button is clicked, I want to create new div tag  with UNIQUE ID with bird as a background and use the code as below accordingly to show the animation. My code is not working and I cannot find my mistake being new to jquery and javascript.

Also, which one is better for efficiency? Creating unique ID for each tag or assigning them as an array value?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    bird_count = 0;
    $("button").click(function () {

        var bird = document.createElement('div');
        bird.setAttribute('id', "bird" + bird_count);
        wrapper.appendChild(bird);
        num_var = 0;
        while (num_var < 29) {

            $("#bird").animate({
                top: '-=5px',
                right: '-=5px',
            }, 50);
            num_var = num_var + 1;
        }
        bird_count = bird_count + 1;
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you need to assign all the birds IDs? You already have a reference to the birds, those are _your_ birds, you have a reference to them.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I want to make new bird animate in background as when the user clicks the button. So, my thought was that <div> should have unique ID each time. Can you please explain please?

Comment: Would you be interested in an answer that provides this functionality without having sequential IDs?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Please!

Comment: maybe @BenjaminGruenbaum wants to explain is that if you're not going to use the "ID", you could use a class to refer to the new element

Comment: @andresdescalzo: Actually, I am trying that right now. Hopefully, it works.

Comment: you button here doesn't have "#" or "." (class or id property)

Comment: @andresdescalzo No, what I was saying is that he already _has_ a reference to the bird, he created it. There is no need to further identify it in the DOM as a unique entity.

Comment: You can see the answer for the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782825/how-to-add-unique-id-to-dynamically-generated-inputs/37424649#37424649)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your HTML is something like:

```
<button id='makeBird'>Make a new bird!</button>
<div id='wrapper'></div>
```

Which is reasonable for your JS code.

Let's see how we can write JS that avoids stuff like `"#name"+number`.

Ths following creates a single bird every time the button is clicked. It adds numbers to them.

```
var button = document.getElementById("makeBird"); // get the button and wrapper elements
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");

var counter = 0; //our counter
button.onclick = function () { // when you click on the button
    var bird = document.createElement('div'); // make a new bird
    var birdNumber = counter; // assign it a counter number
    counter++; // and increase the counter
    bird.className = "bird";
    bird.onclick = function () { // when you click on it
        alert("HI, I'm bird "+birdNumber); // it tells you which bird it is
    }
    $(bird).animate({ // when we create the bird, animate it
        right: '-=400px',
    }, 10000);
    wrapper.appendChild(bird); // append our bird to the wrapper.
};
```

#### You can see a [Working Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Wah9/)

PS, if we place our JS code at the bottom of the `<body>` section of our code, we can avoid `document.ready`

Here is a [jQuerified](http://jsfiddle.net/Usdk4/) solution, in case you're into that.

[Here is a jQuerified version wrapped in a loop that creates 29 birds on click](http://jsfiddle.net/DXJ49/)

Comment: Wow! You actually gave me more that what  I was expecting...That's perfect....Wonderful!

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades I'm glad I helped, please feel free to ask any more question in SO. Stuff like `$("#bird"+counter)` is an anti pattern. In some way in the code above we're using a core concept in coding graphical application and in programming in general called 'separation of concerns'. The bird display object (the div) should not be aware of the bird properties (like its count, which is stored in a JS variable and not the dom).

Comment: In your working demo, every one of the bird starts from different position. What can be done to make each bird start from same position when responding to the click? I tried changing the position to absolute but it won't do. Any suggestions?

Comment: My Bad! There were other problems I was having...thanks you once again.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this example can help:

```
$("button").click(function () {

    var bird = document.createElement('div');
    bird.className = 'bird'; // thanks @BenjaminGruenbaum
    wrapper.appendChild(bird);

    for(var num_var = 0; num_var < 29; num_var++) {
        $(bird).animate({
            top: '-=5px',
            right: '-=5px',
        }, 50);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/)

this is already present in jquery UI and generates OR removes id that are unique and generate on runtime by jquery UI

NOTE:- Jquery UI is a large library to solve this kind of problem.. so this answer is only applicable if you are already using jquery UI

Comment: @ParvSharma I did not downvote you Parv, but your solution was LIKE THROWING NUCLEAR BOMB TO WIPE OUT COLONY OF ANTS.

Comment: ok yeah i recognize that jquery UI is a large library.. because im used to using it a lot i just mentioned it.. i have edited my ans