# how to get the clicked button event id

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i need to get the event id in this table which when the btnStopEvent is clicked its gets the current time and displays it into the same table,i the Endtime Column e.g i have 5 events id 1,2,3,4,5 when the user click the button in column 2 it should display the current time in EndTime Column, Here is what i have for now

```
function GetStartUserData() {
        var IPAddress = $('#IPAddress').text();
        (IPAddress == '' ? null : 'ipaddress=' + IPAddress)
        var EventId = '';
        var Category = $('#categories').val();
        var ExtraData = $('#txtcomment').val();

        return {
          MachineName: IPAddress
        , EventId: EventId
        , CategoryName: Category
        , Comments: ExtraData

        }
}


function DisplayStartData(downTimeStart) {
     console.log(downTimeStart);
     var newContent = '';

        $.each(downTimeStart.data, function (i, item) {
            newContent += Hesto.Html.StartTR(item.downTimeStart);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD('<input type="button" value="Stop" id="btnStopEvent">');
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.EventId);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.CategoryName);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.StartTime);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.EndTime);
            newContent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.Comments);
            newContent  = Hesto.Html.EndTR(newContent);
        });
        $('#DowntimeList').append(newContent);     
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="panel"><table id="Downtimetable" class="hesto">
            <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>END OF DOWNTIME</th> 
                     <th>Event ID</th>                  
                     <th>CATEGORY NAME</th>             
                     <th>START TIME</th>
                     <th>END TIME</th>
                     <th>COMMENTS</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody id="DowntimeList">

             </tbody>
             <tfoot>
             </tfoot>
        </table></div>
  <div class="label" id="IPAddress"><%Response.Write(Request.QueryString["ipaddress"]); %></div>
```

json page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Hesto.SQL;
using Hesto;


public partial class services_json_DownTimeStartByMachineName : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        nvc.AddFromQueryString(Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("MachineName", Request.UserHostAddress, Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("EventId", "NULL", Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("CategoryName","NULL",Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("StartTime",DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("Comments", "NULL", Request.QueryString);

        StoredProcedureCaller spc = new StoredProcedureCaller();
        spc.Execute(Request.QueryString, Resources.StoredProcedureDefinitions.DownTimeStartTimeByMachineName, Resources.ConnectionStrings.HESTOTESTING);

        Response.Write(spc.ToString("json"));
    }
}
```

json page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using Hesto.SQL;
using Hesto;

public partial class services_json_DownTimeStop : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection nvc = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
        nvc.AddFromQueryString(Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("EventId","", Request.QueryString);
        nvc.AddFromQueryString("EndTime", DateTime.Now.ToString(), Request.QueryString);

        StoredProcedureCaller spc = new StoredProcedureCaller();
        spc.Execute(nvc, Resources.StoredProcedureDefinitions.DownTimeStopEvent, Resources.ConnectionStrings.HESTOTESTING);
        Response.Write(spc.ToString("json"));
    }
}
```

Comment: when the btnstopevent button is clicked i want it to display the current time in the newcontent += Hesto.Html.CreateTD(item.EndTime); column only.

Comment: It's very difficult for me to understand what you're trying to do here. It might help if you post a working example on http://jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Provide html code with this otherwise it is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onclick method:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(eventID)">Click me</button>
```

then you can pass your "event id" to JS part:

```
function myFunction(eventID){
alert("Your Event ID : " + eventID);
}
```

or you can use jquery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    alert(this.id); // or alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[Getting ID of clicked element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10291034/2653036)

Comment: when i click the button is says undefined reason being is the button has the same id $('#btnStopEvent')how to i assign each button on different rows i.e[tr]with different event id's?

Comment: you can not use same id for more than one button, I am not sure how to make it using only js, but possibly you should keep a variable, add this variable as text part to you id name, and increment this variable for each row - [tr], thus to have unique id's.

Comment: You can try this: [Unique identifier for HTML elements] (http://stackoverflow.com/a/3298600/2653036)

Comment: can you please give me an example of row[tr]

Comment: You can try this: [How to add unique ID to dynamically generated inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3782835/2653036)

Comment: Use this:
'<html>  
<head>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script>  
  var new_id = 0;
 
  $(document).ready(function(){   
   $('#tbl > tbody > tr').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('id',  "item_no" + '_' + new_id++);
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
      <table id="tbl">
   <tr>
    <td>
   <input type="text" size="2" value="1"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
   <input type="text" size="2" value="4"/>
    </td>
   </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>'

Comment: Notes: I have used JS ' $(document).ready(function(){...code..});' function, which captures your whole document at the very moment it is opened. Then, I used '$('#tbl > tbody > tr')' table id '#tbl' to get its 'tr' element, and after getting that element I iterate over each 'tr' of the table, and set unique 'ids' for each of them.