# Java hashcode reverse calculation

Tags: java, int, hashcode, string-hashing

I am trying to test out how `String` hashcode works by adding a new character and do the reverse to subtract it out, however it didn't give me the right answer when i did the calculation.

For example

```
int PRIME = 31;

//this will print 1687846330 
System.out.println("mlkjihgfedcb".hashCode());   

//this will print 783628775 which equals to "mlkjihgfedcba".hashCode();
System.out.println(("mlkjihgfedcb".hashCode() * PRIME + (int) 'a')); 

//this will print 25278344 which doesn't equals to "mlkjihgfedcb".hashCode()
System.out.println(("mlkjihgfedcba".hashCode() - (int) 'a') / PRIME);
```

I am wondering did i do the math right on my last step above ? overflow shouldn't matter for the calculation right ?

Comment: It's not reversible. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406775/why-does-string-hashcode-in-java-have-many-conflicts

Comment: this is wrong on so many levels

Comment: @Bill I don't see people explain about why is it not reversible in that thread...where do you see it ?

Comment: If two different strings can produce the same result, you could not know which one of those strings produced that hash code, so you could not reverse the calculation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hash functions are not reversible functions.
As proof, consider the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), you can only store values in the integer range in a hashCode but there are an infinite number of Strings. Therefore, there must be multiple strings with the same hashCode (and there are).

Answer (score 5):

Multiplying a big number by 31 leads to integer overflow, which cannot be reversed using division by 31.

But hold on though: arithmetic using `int` in Java is equivalent to arithmetic modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. Since 31 is odd it has a [multiplicative inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. Therefore multiplication by 31 can be reversed with multiplication by the said "inverse." That is:

```
int inverse = -1108378657;
// This will print the hashCode of mlkjihgfedcb
System.out.println(("mlkjihgfedcba".hashCode() - (int) 'a') * inverse);
```

Comment: how do we get or calculate the inverse number ?

Comment: You can use the extended Euclidean algorithm, or use [Hensel's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma#Hensel.27s_Lemma_for_p-adic_Numbers). The latter is easiest to implement: first set `x = a = 31` and then repeat `x = x*(2-a*x)` until it converges, up to five times.

Comment: But you don't have to calculate it, it's -1108378657

Answer (score 2):

The specific reason this fails is

```
1687846330 * 31 + 97 = 52323236327
```

The number 52,323,236,327 is much larger than what an `int` can hold, so information is lost off the left-hand end.  That information cannot be recovered by inverting the `hashCode()` algorithm.

If you do the arithmetic you'll see that the hash code you got for the second string is exactly *52323236327 mod 2<sup>31</sup>*

More important, the mapping from objects to hash codes is intended to be *opaque* and non-reversible.  Just because it's implemented in a specific way today does not mean the next version of the library has to do it the same way.  The only guarantee is that the possibility of collision is extremely low (but non-zero).

Comment: I don't know any way the behavior of the string's hash function could change without breaking any `switch` statements that use a string argument, since the compiled code includes hardcoded hash values for the strings.