# DeadLock In ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

Following code when run, never terminates and stuck in endless loop.

I am not sure where it is getting stuck.

Interesting thing is when I change `AaAa` to `AAAA` every thing works fine as expected.

```
 public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(16);
        map.computeIfAbsent(
                "AaAa",
                key -> {
                    return map.computeIfAbsent(
                            "BBBB",
                            key2 -> 42);
                }
        );
    }

}
```

Can some one help me understanding this behavior.

Comment: FYI : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406775/why-does-string-hashcode-in-java-have-many-conflicts

Answer (score 16):

`"AaAa"` and `"BBBB"` have the same `hashCode()` - 2031744.
Therefore both keys are mapped to the same bin of the Map.

The outer `map.computeIfAbsent` locks that bin, and the inner `map.computeIfAbsent` tries to lock it before the lock is released - hence the deadlock.

Comment: @Eran--OMG how do you check all this so quickly ...awesome stuff...(Y)

Comment: @ShowStopper I happen to be sitting next to a computer with Eclipse open, so it doesn't take much time to run `System.out.println ("AaAa".hashCode ());` and `System.out.println ("BBBB".hashCode ());` :)

Comment: I love it when those perfect answers come in quickly. I just hate it when I am not the author of it. Still, you got my vote.

Comment: Some [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9406775/why-does-string-hashcode-in-java-have-many-conflicts) conflicts for `String.hashCode()` .

Comment: But the interesting thing is that, should not hashcode() generate unique hash value for two different String?

Comment: @MehrajMalik No, it should not and cannot. The are 2^32 unique hashCodes. There are many more unique Strings.

Comment: @Eran Thanks, **a2 * 31^2 + b2** I got clear answer by merging your theory with this formulate.

Comment: It's interesting that a thread can deadlock itself this way. Normal `synchronized` uses reentrant monitor locks that don't have this problem, but I guess `ConcurrentHashMap` uses some type of lock that does. I wonder if this should be considered a bug?

Comment: @ruakh--Why are you pointing it to bug , its the user who created dead lock not the implementation ...:( Could you please explain it bit more seems you have interesting point here

Comment: @ShowStopper: I suggested that it might be a bug because client code shouldn't have to worry about the exact lock implementation used by `ConcurrentHashMap`; but I was wrong, because I now see that [the documentation for `computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) explicitly says not to do this, so the client code is indeed ill-behaved.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever two different objects have the same hash code, we call this a `collision`.

A collision is nothing critical, it just means that there is more than one object in a single bucket, so a `HashMap` lookup has to look again to find the right object. A lot of collisions will degrade the performance of a system, but they won’t lead to incorrect results.

But if you mistake the hash code for a unique handle to an object, e.g use it as a key in a `Map`, **then you will sometimes get the wrong object**.

In `Java` there are `4,294,967,296` compartments (`2^32` possible `int` values). With 4 billion slots, collisions seem to be extremely unlikely, right? **Because even though collisions are rare, they are inevitable**. For example, the Strings `"Aa"` and `"BB"` produce the same `hashCode: 2112`.`"AaAa"` and `"BBBB"` have the same `hashCode() - 2031744` and many more.

**Objects that are equal must have the same hash code within a running process**

Please note that this does not imply the following common misconceptions:

- Unequal objects must have different hash codes – **WRONG**!
- Objects with the same hash code must be equal – **WRONG**!