# Generate unique number based on string input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, unique

In the past I have made a function that generates an unique id (number) from a string. Today I discover that it is not as unique as should be. Never saw a problem before with it. Today two different inputs generates the same id (number).

I use the same technique in Delphi, C++, PHP and Javascript to generate the same id's so there is no difference when different languages are involved to a project. For example this can be handy to communicate, for HTML id's, tempfiles etc.

In general, what I do is calculate a CRC16 of a string, add the sum and return it.

For example, these two strings generate the same id (number):

```
o.uniqueId( 'M:/Mijn Muziek/Various Artists/Revs & ElBee - Tell It To My Heart.mp3' );
o.uniqueId( 'M:/Mijn Muziek/Various Artists/Dwight Yoakam - The Back Of Your Hand.Mp3');
```

They both generates an id of 224904.

The following example is a javascript example. My question is, how can i avoid (with a little change) that it generates a duplicate? (In case you might wonder what 'o.' means, it is the object where these functions belongs to):

```
o.getCrc16 = function(s, bSumPos) {
  if(typeof s !== 'string' || s.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  var crc = 0xFFFF,
    L = s.length,
    sum = 0,
    x = 0,
    j = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    j = s.charCodeAt(i);
    sum += ((i + 1) * j);
    x = ((crc >> 8) ^ j) & 0xFF;
    x ^= x >> 4;
    crc = ((crc << 8) ^ (x << 12) ^ (x << 5) ^ x) & 0xFFFF;
  }
  return crc + ((bSumPos ? 1 : 0) * sum);
}
o.uniqueId = function(s, bres) {
  if(s == undefined || typeof s != 'string') {
    if(!o.___uqidc) {
      o.___uqidc = 0;
    } else {
      ++o.___uqidc;
    }
    var od = new Date(),
      i = s = od.getTime() + '' + o.___uqidc;
  } else {
    var i = o.getCrc16(s, true);
  }
  return((bres) ? 'res:' : '') + (i + (i ? s.length : 0));
};
```

How can I avoid duplicates with use of a little change to the code?

Comment: If you're "hashing" long string into a short ID, [you may encounter collision someday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All right, did allot of testing and come to this. A relative short unique id generated by the following:

```
o.lz = function(i,c)
{
  if( typeof c != 'number' || c <= 0 || (typeof i != 'number' && typeof i != 'string') )
   { return i; }
  i+='';

  while( i.length < c )
   { i='0'+i; }
  return i;  
}

o.getHashCode = function(s)
{
 var hash=0,c=(typeof s == 'string')?s.length:0,i=0;
 while(i<c) 
 {
   hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+s.charCodeAt(i++);
   //hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
 }

 return ( hash < 0 )?((hash*-1)+0xFFFFFFFF):hash; // convert to unsigned
}; 

o.uniqueId = function( s, bres )
{ 
  if( s == undefined || typeof s != 'string' )
  { 
     if( !o.___uqidc )
      { o.___uqidc=0; }
     else { ++o.___uqidc; } 
     var od = new Date(),
         i = s = od.getTime()+''+o.___uqidc; 
  }
  else { var i = o.getHashCode( s ); }
  return ((bres)?'res:':'')+i.toString(32)+'-'+o.lz((s.length*4).toString(16),3);  
};
```

Examples:

```
o.uniqueId( 'M:/Mijn Muziek/Various Artists/Revs & ElBee - Tell It To My Heart.mp3' );
o.uniqueId( 'M:/Mijn Muziek/Various Artists/Dwight Yoakam - The Back Of Your Hand.Mp3');
```

Will produce the following id's:

```
dh8qi9t-114
je38ugg-120
```

For my purpose it seems to be unique enough, also the extra length adds some more uniqueness. Test it on filesystem with approx 40.000 mp3 files and did not found any collision.

If you think this is not the way to go, please let me know.

Comment: could you confirm it really was "unique enough" for your purpose?

Comment: @Paolo: No, cannot confirm it however, use it nowerdays (2018, answer was in 2013) in many projects, in Pascal, C/C++, PHP and Javascript and didn't find any problems. It is also very usable for generating short Id's or (control-)hashes or filenames etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the number of bits created by your hash function. Assuming that your hash function approximately uniform over the space, you can mathematically derive the probability of observing a collision.

This is strongly related to the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox). In the case of CRC16, where the hash value is 17 bits (though your implementation may have a mistake; I don't see how you obtained `224094` as that is greater than `2^17`), you will have a collision probability above 50% when you store more than approximately 2^8 items. In addition, CRC is not really a great hashing function because it's meant for error detection, not uniform hashing.

[This table shows mathematical probabilities of collision based on hash length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_paradox#Probability_table). For example, if you have a 128-bit hash key, you can store up to `10^31` elements before the collision probability increases beyond `10^-15`. As a comparison, this probability is lower than that of your hard drive failing, or maybe your computer being zapped by lightning, so a safe number to use.

Just increase your hash length based on the number of strings you are planning to identify, and a pick a collision probability that is acceptable to you.

Comment: Okay, that is a clear answer (in some way) to me. To explain the higher CRC value, this is caused because of the multiply by the sum. Do you know a good example (source code) to get an unique id from a string? I am not a math guy anyway.

Comment: [Generate a Hash from string in Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: That looks quite easy. But see some complains about it's uniqueness. Is it true?

Comment: The accepted answer is for a 32-bit hash. But check out the other answers as well.

Comment: Is that usable for a personal mp3 library of approx. 10.000 entries or more?

Comment: I ask this because i don't how it is possible that a filesharing service like divShare can use such short file id like: '726721-2d6' for a file. They got 2,793,106 users. How is this possible?