# How to implement javascript int.toString(32) in PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, hex

I have a uniqueId function that generates an unique ID of a string. I use this in javascript, you can find it here (see my answer):
[Generate unique number based on string input in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15377161/generate-unique-number-based-on-string-input-in-javascript)

I want to do the same the same in PHP, but the function produces mostly floats instead of unsigned ints (beyond signed int value `PHP_MAX_INT`) and because of that i cannot use the PHP function `dechex()` to convert it to hex. `dechex()` is limited to PHP_MAX_INT value so every value above the `PHP_MAX_INT` will be returned as `FFFFFFFF`.

In javascript instead, when using int.toString(32), it produces a string with other letters than A..F, for example:

```
dh8qi9t
je38ugg
```

How do I achieve the same result in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest `base_convert($input,10,32)`, but as you observed it won't work for numbers that are too big.

Instead, you could implement it yourself:

```
function big_base_convert($input,$from,$to) {
  $out = "";
  $alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  while($input > 0) {
    $next = floor($input/$to);
    $out = $alphabet[$input-$next*$to].$out; // note alternate % operation
    $input = $next;
  }
  return $out ?: "0";
}
```

Comment: base_convert($input,10,32) does the 'trick' very well. Many thanks!

Comment: eh, just one question: How do i convert it back to an unsigned int?