# Jquery checksum

Tags: jquery, asp.net, checksum

I'm building a kiosk contest that will run on an iPad, and I've built it so that once the form loads, it can run offline by storing each entry using localStorage.

Every 15 minutes, the webpage will attempt to send the entries back to the server, and if successful, the local records will be deleted from localStorage.

Now to the crux of it:

For safety purposes, I can't have the iPad issue a delete command unless we're absolutely certain the server received all of the records.

If bandwidth was not an issue, I would simply have the server send back all of the records it received, the ipad would check the received data from the server against what it sent to the server, and if the two match, we can be confident the server received all of the records and empty the localStorage variable.

Since bandwidth is an issue, I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a checksum on the data, send the data, have the .asp receiving file generate a checksum as well and just send the checksum back as a response.

So I guess my question is, is there a way to generate a checksum in jQuery that can be duplicated in .ASP?

Thanks,
B

Comment: In simple, whatever you do at client side they are not secure

Comment: @SivaCharan It doesn't need to be secure.  This is not a high security app, and it will be running on a single, supervised Ipad.  I'm not at all concerned that someone can corrupt the data, I just need to make sure that the data has been saved on the server before clearing out the localStorage

Comment: Ok. Data is in which form?

Comment: @SivaCharan localStorage is stored as a string, so it will be one long string (JSON.stringify output)

Comment: Refer my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16153781/500725)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the hash value with this function

```
String.prototype.hashCode = function(){
    var hash = 0, i, char;
    if (this.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        char = this.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
        hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
};
```

Function is taken from **esmiralha**'s answer **[Generate a Hash from string in Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616484/500725)**

Comment: Interesting, thank you, and as I'm not an asp coder, how would I replicate this code in asp, please?