# Alphanumeric hash function in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hash

I am looking for a way to covert a given string into an alphanumeric hash. The code will be executed on the client-side and must be entirely in vanilla JS or jQuery at the most.

Is there, however, also a *non-cryptographic* hash, i.e. just a string of alphanumerics that does not require `crypto` and `Promises`? I need both, i.e. a cryptographic as well as a non-cryptographic hash.

The second hash can be an ordinary string of alphanumerics, say 10 characters long. It should be recoverable, i.e. the same hash should be recreated always for a given string. It would be better if this second hash is not generated asynchronously (i.e. using `Promises`). I intend to use it as a key for a `boolean` in `window.localStorage` (for many different strings).

**Final answers:**

- [Crypto JS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)
- [bcrypt.js](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js/blob/master/README.md)
- [Fast low-collision non-crypto hash in JavaScript for
  Files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16225632/3287204)

Comment: There's a built-in object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto

Comment: Something like `window.crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", new TextEncoder().encode("my string"))` should do.

Comment: Note that according to that MDN link, Crypto is only guaranteed for ie11+.

Comment: @Evk Do you mind using the answer box? ;)

Comment: Does this require encryption or does mere encoding work? base64 is fairly simple via `btoa(string)` and available in IE10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modern browsers provide cryptographic algorithms implementation via `window.crypto` object. You can look at what "modern" means in this case by [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) link (at the bottom). If you are fine with supported browsers list, then you can reach your goal for example like this:

```
async function hash(target){
   var buffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", new TextEncoder().encode(target));
   var chars = Array.prototype.map.call(new Uint8Array(buffer), ch => String.fromCharCode(ch)).join('');
   return btoa(chars);
};
```

It will hash your string (bytes of its utf-8 encoding) with SHA-256 and then convert result to base64.

Note that if you don't need cryptographically strong hash (you didn't clarify the purpose) - then there might be better (faster) alternatives.

Comment: And what properties do you need from such hash, what's a usage?

Comment: Maybe then just use a library such as CryptoJS (https://github.com/brix/crypto-js)? Then you can use something like `CryptoJS.MD5("your string")`, and no promises. Or you may look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/16225632/5311735

Comment: No vanilla JS like in your first answer ? :)

Comment: Well this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14733374/5311735 has some copy-pastable MD5 implementations, you might consider them.