# Why check against a prototype rather than the instance?

Tags: javascript

I was just reading [this answer regarding hashing in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710692/304588), and, while it was definitely faster than the accepted answer, it requires the `reduce` function on the `Array` prototype.

Checking the existence of the `reduce` function is easy enough; but while most checks I do (and have seen) check against the prototype, it just made me wonder: what are the implications of checking against an instance itself? Why does the prototype check seem to be preferred?

```
// i.e.

if (!!Array.prototype.reduce) { }
// vs
if (!![].reduce)
```

The instance will definitely need an instance, so that's one thing, but is that it?

Comment: `Array` can *technically* be overwritten, but the constructor `[]` cannot

Comment: @Ian—if Array is overwritten, you've got bigger issues to deal with… ;-)

Comment: either way, you can omit the "!!" since methods "if" to true or undefined, which is false... If you're checking for an array method, you probably have an array already, so you don't need the empty one to hit "if(myArr.reduce)", and sniffing your exact variable is more accurate to boot.

Comment: The main argument will be that `[]` is much shorter to type…

Comment: @dandavis ~ your second point is fair, but not applicable if, for example, I'm writing an extension of a plugin most probably, as I'd most probably be operating on a "much more general" sense. As for the `!!`, I write it whenever I explicitly want a boolean, just to be clear (to others, and to myself). True enough on the `if` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ran a benchmark: http://jsperf.com/prototype-vs-instance-property-check

`Array.prototype.reduce` is 3x faster due to the instantiation of an empty array, but realistically, there is absolutely no difference since these checks are almost always one-time checks, and not in code that runs all the time.

I personally have reduced this to `[].method` for years.  I do the same for things like `Array.prototype.slice.call( .. )` vs `[].slice.call( ... )`, and those are called far more often than once.

But note that this is only valid on `Array`, so you're really not saving a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The second version involves needlessly instantiating an empty array. Why do so, when you can just ask the prototype itself and not instantiate anything?

Comment: I did mention that, but was just wondering if that was all there was to it. Not to say that the overhead is negligible though; I recognize this *and* perform the `prototype` check even for just this reason.

Comment: @RichardNeilIlagan I think that besides inintiating an empty array to invoke the function ([].reduce) the JS runtime has to look up the object instance prototype chain to find it. Where as Array.prototype.reduce tells the runtime exactly where to find it.

Comment: @HMR—actually, the lookup on an instance's `[[Prototype]]` is shorter and therefore *should* be faster as an empty array only has one property (*length*) to check. So the lookup will go almost directly to the prototype. With the pure property method, the identifier *Array* must be resolved on the scope chain before starting to look for *prototype* amongst Array's properties (there are two). But using an instance may not be faster as resolving identifiers in the global scope seems very fast (it's almost as if browsers check global before the local variable object).