# Generate unique UID from some specific string in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to generate unique UID from some specific string in javascript.

eq.

```
var string = "this is some string that will generate unique UID"  
var unique_UID = somefunction(string)
```

and everytime when I will call `somefunction(string)` this will generate same unique_UID if the string is same.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `function somefunction (str) { return str; }` looks unique to me.

Comment: while it does not generate a uuid from a string [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/how-to-create-a-guid-uuid-in-javascript) do generate unique ids, you could probably modify them to use a string as the seed

Comment: Do you expect to get different, unique results when you give the same input string? Or are you just asking how to scramble the string into something that looks random (i.e. a hash code)?

Comment: @PatrickEvans that function return random uid because use Math.random and everytime is used will generate another UID

Comment: @Barmar I expect to get same UID as long the string is same

Comment: Then use a hashing function like `MD5`, `SHA1`, or one of the algorithms in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php

Comment: @Barmar I need that function in JavaScript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a Hash from string in Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I totally agree with @epascarello It is exactly what you need. What is wrong with this solution? It satisfies all the conditions you've mentioned. Also `function somefunction(str){return 1;}` satisfies your conditions. You have to be more precise in what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a hash function. Try to use [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#The_Hasher_Algorithms):

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
<script>
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("Message");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this

```
function randomString(str) {
    var uid = ''; str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
    for (var i = str.length; i > 0; --i) {
        uid += str[Math.round(Math.random() * (str.length - 1))];
    }
    return uid;
}
var uid = randomString('this is some string that will generate unique UID');
console.log(uid); // tnwtrieitiUnilwuteerhnrnthtqwritmutteqeua
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/KTt3z/1/)