# integer hash in range from string

Tags: javascript, hash

I am writing a function that needs to return a 'random' number from a given string,
starting from:

```
function hashNumberBetween(str, start, end){
  ....
  return num;
}

// same string and same length return same number
hashNumberBetween('getjnigejgr', 0, 10); // 4
hashNumberBetween('getjnigejgr', 0, 10); // 4

// but, same string and different length return different number
hashNumberBetween('getjnigejgr', 0, 32); // 15

hashNumberBetween('jukojmnktgo', 0, 10); // 6
```

what is the right way to achieve the same combination given the same string? I reckon it is some sort of hash function. Any online resource I can look at? Might sound a really easy question but I don't know how to search for it.

Comment: Yes you could do this by creating a hash function for the string (see [Generate a Hash from string in Javascript/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery)). Then you can use the resulting hash value to extract the appropriate values.

Comment: Does anyone solved this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From your question I guess you can already return a random combination of colors and animals.

To achieve the desired behaviour you need a hash function to convert string into integer.

So just pick one of these [Javascript hash functions](http://erlycoder.com/49/javascript-hash-functions-to-convert-string-into-integer-hash-)  or search for others on google (there is no need to reinvent the wheel).

Hope this helps, have a nice day,

Alberto

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score -1):

Is it something like password in database?

You pass some password string `myPassword123` => convert it to crc32/md5 etc. => search in database for generated string => return user name by password.