# String to Unique hash in Javascript / Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a function in Javascript / Jquery which will make hashtag from a string ? I'm looking for the answer for few minutes and i can't find it :/ Maybe there is some other way to make it ? I have Symfony 2.4 application.

I have my form data serialized to string, for example:

```
"cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5BdictName%5D=Otwartabbb&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5BdictValue1%5D=fa-comments-o+text-muted&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B1%5D%5BdictName%5D=Wycena&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B1%5D%5BdictValue1%5D=fa-comments-o+text-muted&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B1%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B2%5D%5BdictName%5D=Negocjacje&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B2%5D%5BdictValue1%5D=fa-comments-o+text-muted&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B2%5D%5BisDefault%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B2%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B3%5D%5BdictName%5D=Wygrana&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B3%5D%5BdictValue1%5D=fa-thumbs-o-up+text-primary&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B3%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B4%5D%5BdictName%5D=Przegrana&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B4%5D%5BdictValue1%5D=fa-thumbs-o-down+text-danger&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B4%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5B_token%5D=3PBJr_pPjHhAIB95N7PUReP5asrXsGwCILAxZLyGTUg deal:738
cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5BdictName%5D=w%C5%82asnee&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B0%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B1%5D%5BdictName%5D=proklienckii&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B1%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B2%5D%5BdictName%5D=telemarketing&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B2%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B3%5D%5BdictName%5D=mailing&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B3%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B4%5D%5BdictName%5D=www&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B4%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B5%5D%5BdictName%5D=partner&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B5%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B6%5D%5BdictName%5D=nowe+zrodlo&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B6%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B7%5D%5BdictName%5D=Aaa&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5Bitems%5D%5B7%5D%5BdictActive%5D=1&cloud_adm_dictionary_type%5B_token%5D=3PBJr_pPjHhAIB95N7PUReP5asrXsGwCILAxZLyGTUg"
```

And i want to make hashtag from that, something like i Don't know '462423dfdaak542634'. I need later to compare hashtags to see if the form was changed or not.

Comment: show some example of which string you want to convert to what?

Comment: A whole 'few minutes' hey? Bet that was taxing. ;)

Comment: Abdul -> I have added informations which u wanted.

Comment: hashtag is something else -__- what you need is a simple function which will return a unique hash value for your strings!

Comment: Similar question with answers: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here, you can use this simple hashing function:

```
function hashCode (str){
    var hash = 0;
    if (str.length == 0) return hash;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        char = str.charCodeAt(i);
        hash = ((hash<<5)-hash)+char;
        hash = hash & hash; // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash;
}
```

**[See the DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/othgaf1h/)**

Comment: Welcome.. oh and btw.. hashtag referes to "#" so i was first thinking you want your strings converted to #String #anotherString.. haha

Comment: I know, My mistake. I later thought that there are hashtags on facebook and it wasn't luckiest word for what I need :P And now I know why I couldn't find an answer for this in google xD

Comment: Works well, but i and char variables are not defined, and that's really dangerous.

Comment: Duplicate at least try making your own code OMG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript