# How can I prevent false scores to leadersboard table with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, game-development

I´m using PHP (I´m a total newbie with this) to get/set the scores of my games and everything is working perfectly, but it´s pretty easy to hack as I´m making my games with Javascript and the user can check the code and see the jQuery part where I send this info to the server like this

```
$.post( "http://theurl/addScore.php", { game: 1, name: myPlayer, score: Number(myScore) });
```

I guess there´s no a perfect solution, but at least I want to know how can I turn that "hack" more difficult to the cheater.

Any way to prevent such an easy insert in the database?

Comment: You can try to encoding the data that you send to server

Comment: You could edit all the filenames and the var-names and instead of passing all vars manually you could create a array with a random name or something like 'getPlayerData'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: There is really no way of protecting it. You can pass up all the moves to the server and do validation there to see if it score adds up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Minify your javascript.
2. On the serverside check for abnormal scores which can't be possible, if so block IP/User.
3. Encode clientside data, decode on the serverside.

Comment: Well, when I finish the game I always minify the js code, that´s normal.

About blocking users... I don´t like that too much, it could be a bug and it would be unfair to block that user, not a good option for me.

About encoding in the clientside, is this really an option? Maybe I´m saying something stupid, but if the user sees how the encoding is done, he can hack it anyway (I don´t know if this makes sense...).

Comment: You could also give users a temporary ban. For the encoding, true but it would sure get harder.