# Got duplicated data when subscribe multiple times

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I am using MongoDB aggregation in meteor. I got duplicated data when subscribe multiple times.

(The data in database are static, which means they are same all the time.)

// Server side

```
Meteor.publish('totalNumber', function () {
  let pipeline = [
    { $unwind: '$product' },
    { $group: {
      _id: {
        code: '$product.code',
        hour: { $hour: '$timestamp' }
      },
      total: { $sum: '$product.count' },
    }}
  ];

  Products.aggregate(
    pipeline,
    Meteor.bindEnvironment((err, result) => {
        console.log('result', result);  // at here every time subscribe, no duplicated data
        _.each(result, r => {
          this.added('totalNumber',
            // I use Random.id() here, because "Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids"
            Random.id(), {
              code: r._id.code,
              hour: r._id.hour,
              total: r.total
          });
        });
      }
    )
  );

  this.ready();
});
```

// Client side

```
this.subscribe('totalNumber', () => {
  // Correct result: [Object, Object] for example
  console.log(Products.find().fetch());
}, true);

this.subscribe('totalNumber', () => {
  // Wrong result: [Object, Object, Object, Object]
  console.log(Products.find().fetch());
}, true);

this.subscribe('totalNumber', () => {
  // Wrong result: [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
  console.log(Products.find().fetch());
}, true);
```

So right now basically, the new results always include last time subscribe data.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Are the ids different for every run through the pipeline?

Comment: @DavidWeldon which ids?

Comment: You are calling `this.added` with `r._id`. Is `r._id`randomly generated, or will the same set of ids be produced each time the pipline is run?

Comment: Sorry, u are right, I updated my question, I actually used `Random.id()` in my code, so they are different.

Comment: Yeah that's your problem. It's like telling the client "I added `{_id: 'a', total: 10}`" and then later telling it "I added `{_id: 'b', total: 10}`", and expecting there to be be only one object. The client will determine uniqueness by the value in the `_id` field, but if it's random, all of your documents will appear to be unique. I'd write this as an answer but I don't know what to suggest without knowing more about what you are trying to solve.

Comment: @DavidWeldon I added more details in my question. I use `Random.id()` there, because `Meteor does not currently support objects other than ObjectID as ids`, so is there any other way to solve it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a random id each time in the call to `added` so the client always thinks all of the documents are unique. You need to devise a **consistent** id string generator. Using an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery), you could imagine building a set of functions like these:

```
hashCode = function (s) {
  return s.split('').reduce(function (a, b) {
    a = ((a << 5) - a) + b.charCodeAt(0);return a & a;
  }, 0);
};

objectToHash = function (obj) {
  return String(hashCode(JSON.stringify(obj)));
};
```

So if you wanted a unique document for each combination of `code` and `hour` you could do this:

```
var id = objectToHash(r._id);
this.added('totalNumber', id, {...});
```