# How to access aggregated collection data in meteor client?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router, meteor-helper

I aggregated some data and published it, but I'm not sure how/where to access the subscribed data. Would I be able to access WeeklyOrders client collection (which is defined as client-only collection i.e WeeklyOrders = new Mongo.Collection(null);)?

Also, I see "self = this;" being used in several examples online and I just used it here, but not sure why. Appreciate anyone explaining that as well.

Here is publish method:

```
Meteor.publish('customerOrdersByWeek', function(customerId) {
  check(customerId, String);
  var self = this;
  var pipeline = [
    { $match: {customer_id: customerId} },
    { $group: {
        _id : { week: { $week: "$_created_at" }, year: { $year: "$_created_at" } },
        weekly_order_value: { $sum: "$order_value" }
      }
    },
    { $project: { week: "$_id.week", year: "$_id:year" } },
    { $limit: 2 }
  ];
  var result = Orders.aggregate(pipeline);
  result.forEach(function(wo) {
    self.added('WeeklyOrders', objectToHash(wo._id), {year: wo.year, week: wo.week, order_value: wo.weekly_order_value});
  });
  self.ready();
});
```

Here is the route:

```
Router.route('/customers/:_id', {
  name: 'customerOrdersByWeek',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('customerOrdersByWeek', this.params._id)
    ];
  },
  data: function() { return Customers.findOne(this.params._id); }
});
```

Here is my template helper:

```
Template.customerOrdersByWeek.helpers({
  ordersByWeek: function() {
    return WeeklyOrders.find({});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `var self = this` (note the var!) so that call to `self.added` works. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) for more details. Alternatively you can use the new es6 arrow functions (again see the linked question).

There may be more than one issue where, but in your call to `added` you are giving a random id. This presents two problems:

1. If you subscribe N times, you will get N of the same document sent to the client (each with a different id). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023747/got-duplicated-data-when-subscribe-multiple-times) for more details.
2. You can't match the document by id on the client.

On the client, you are doing a `Customers.findOne(this.params._id)` where `this.params._id` is, I assume, a customer id... but your `WeeklyOrders` have random ids. Give this a try:

```
self.added('WeeklyOrders', customerId, {...});
```

---

### updated answer

You'll need to add a [client-only collection](http://phucnguyen.info/blog/how-to-publish-to-a-client-only-collection-in-meteor/) as a sort-of mailbox for your publisher to send `WeeklyOrders` to:

**client/collections/weekly-orders.js**

```
WeeklyOrders = new Meteor.Collection('WeeklyOrders');
```

Also, because you could have multiple docs for the same user, you'll probably need to:

1. Forget what I said earlier and just use a random id, but never subscribe more that once. This is an easy solution but somewhat brittle.
2. Use a compound index (combine the customer id + week, or whatever is necessary to make them unique).

Using (2) and adding a customerId field so you can find the docs on the client, results in something like this:

```
result.forEach(function (wo) {
  var id = customerId + wo.year + wo.week;
  self.added('WeeklyOrders', id, {
    customerId: customerId,
    year: wo.year,
    week: wo.week,
    order_value: wo.weekly_order_value,
  });
});
```

Now on the client you can find all of the `WeeklyOrders` by `customerId` via `WeeklyOrders.find({customerId: someCustomerId})`.

Also note, that instead of using pub/sub you could also just do all of this in a method call. Both are no-reactive. The pub/sub gets you collection semantics (the ability to call `find` etc.), but it adds the additional complexity of having to deal with ids.

Comment: I don't think I can use customerId to replace randomId because all the documents belong to same customer. They are just aggregated by week. I updated the question to reflect your comments, but I still need help with crux of the question. How would I be able to access WeeklyOrders in client?

Comment: I added some more info to the answer. Hopefully that gets you closer to a solution.

Comment: What I had been missing is a client side collection with the same name as the one in self.added i.e. `WeeklyOrders = new Mongo.Collection("WeeklyOrders");`. Without this I couldn't reference the the data that is being published. Please update your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Ah, I missed that you hadn't done that. Oops. Well, I updated the answer. Better late than never I suppose.