# Node.js 10 Digit Hash Code from String

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I have the following strings:

```
"184500000712_1_new_store1",
"184500000712_4_new_store1",
"184500000712_12_new_store1",
"195600000819_1_new_store2",
...
```

I am trying to turn each individual string into a unique 10-digit code like so:

```
184500000712_1_new_store1 => K14K4O9WVQ
184500000712_4_new_store1 => E93N7L2PXC
184500000712_12_new_store1 => A89F5I6JIO
195600000819_1_new_store2 => J00B1I5KFU
```

Also the string-to-code output must always be consistent. Fe, **utf-8 base64** encoding of the string `184500000712_1_new_store1` would always output the code `MTg0NTAwMDAwNzEyXzFfbmV3X3N0b3JlMQ==`

Thanks!

Comment: If you can compress each of the strings into 7.5 bytes (yes, I mean 60 bit), then you can use a pseudo-random permutation to get a unique resulting value. If you can't compress it, then the only way would be to manage a (potentially huge) map of known inputs and randomly generated outputs.

Comment: Nice! I hadn't thought of compression. I have some strings that are 10X the length of the example strings.  Could compression still preserve uniqueness

Comment: As I said, you would need to "compress" the input strings to 60 **bits**. This would only be possible if they are actually of low entropy or you can find a way to compress them yourself, because you can see some kind of rule in them. If you can't then you're out of luck. The best you could then do, is using a hash function, truncate the output to 60 bits, used base64 encoding and remove the padding characters. A cryptographic hash function does not guarantee uniqueness, but it makes collisions improbable.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't need to be a secure hash (which it probably couldn't be, given that it is only 10 characters), you can check this answer for a quick hash generator: [Generate a Hash from string in Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery)

Truncate the string to your desired length and you should be ok. Depending on how many of these you're creating, you may need to be mindful of collisions.