# Javascript string->int injective function

Tags: javascript, string

I want to create a unique ID to a given string while the same ID should be received for that string every time i'm trying to do that, and two different strings should get different IDs.

Let say the size of the strings is limited to x chars, and therefor this injective function is possible.

Are you familiar with a javascript function or a suitable algorithm that would be good fot it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use the string ? What kind of ID do you need ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: use object variable. ex. {id: 1, value:"string"}

Comment: @Weedoze int ID.

Comment: @Arg0n thanks, i will look into it