# javascript - generate reproducible hash (5-10 characters) from various sized strings

Tags: javascript, hash

Take this stackoverflow question:

[Generate a Hash from string in Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery)

I'd like to do exactly that, however I'd like to **generate the same sized hash** no matter what size string is used to generate the hash.

For instance take the following

```
  function genorateHash(string){
       ...do something...
       return hash
 }

  genorateHash("hello")                   output >> "3NCI4KSI"
  genorateHash("THIS IS A LONGER STING")  output >> "4J4IXYEK"
  genorateHash("hello")                   output >> "3NCI4KSI" (Notice "hello" regenerates the same hash every time.)
```

Notice `"hello"` regenerates the same hash every time.

How can this be accomplished?

(I understand it's unlikely to generate the same hash, it something like 8^n?)

---

Also Im working with nodeJS and I haven't seen any `npm` packages that accomplish this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/id-generator

https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid

Thanks

Comment: Couldn't the code in the linked question do that if you added a line to pad or truncate the result to a fixed number of digits?

Comment: Use a standard large-base hashing algorithm (e.g. [SHA-1](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1)) or library and truncate?

Answer (score 1):

If the length of 8 is not important, the [md5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md5) and [sha1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1) algorithms are rather widely used. If you must have that length, I believe [crc32](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crc32) is 8 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate any hash (MD5, SHA) and take its first 8 symbols. It will guarantee that the same input will produce the same 8-symbol string.
Note that whatever hash or algorithm you use, the entropy will be dramatically reduced and the chance of collisions will be pretty high, therefore this hash cannot be used for security purposes anymore.

MD5 / SHA hashes can be generated using different packages:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sha1