# Javascript: Determine and return duplicates objects from array of objects based in multiple keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects:

```
    var data  = [{"monitor":"TFT",
                  "manufacturer":"MONCORP",
                  "monID":"1234",
                  "Delivery Way":"DELIVERY",
                  "BarCode Text":"Test",
                  "BarCode Id":"D9",
                  "Status":"OK"},               

                 {"monitor":"LCD",
                  "manufacturer":"MONCORP",
                  "monID":"",
                  "Delivery Way":"PICKUP",
                  "BarCode Text":"Dummy Text",
                  "BarCode Id":"P2",
                  "Status":"OK"},

                 {"monitor":"TFT",
                  "manufacturer":"MONCORP",
                  "monID":"1234",
                  "Delivery Way":"DELIVERY",
                  "BarCode Text":"ONLY TEST",
                  "BarCode Id":"D9",
                  "Status":"OK"}, 

                 {"monitor":"LCD",
                  "manufacturer":"MONCORP",
                  "monID":"1234",
                  "Delivery Way":"DELIVERY",
                  "BarCode Text":"FOR TESTING PURPOSE",
                  "BarCode Id":"D9",
                  "Status":"OK"},

                  {"monitor":"TFT",
                   "manufacturer":"MONCORP",
                   "monID":"",
                   "Delivery Way":"PICKUP",
                   "BarCode Text":"DUMMIEST TEXT",
                   "BarCode Id":"P7",
                   "Status":"OK"}];
```

So I want to take only the objects that are duplicated, BUT I want to distinguish them according to values of keys: monitor, manufacturer, monID, Delivery Way, BarCode Id, Status.

The expected result is:

```
    expected = [{"monitor":"TFT",
                 "manufacturer":"MONCORP",
                 "monID":"1234",
                 "Delivery Way":"DELIVERY",
                 "BarCode Text":"Test",
                 "BarCode Id":"D9",
                 "Status":"OK"},

                {"monitor":"TFT",
                 "manufacturer":"MONCORP",
                 "monID":"1234",
                 "Delivery Way":"DELIVERY",
                 "BarCode Text":"ONLY TEST",
                 "BarCode Id":"D9",
                 "Status":"OK"}]
```

Comment: by 'I want to distinguish them according to values of keys:..' do you mean you want to ignore the differences for 'BarCode Text'? (or any other key not in the list?)

Comment: Yes exactly i am only interested for the list: monitor, manufacturer, monID, Delivery Way, BarCode Id, Status.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a good idea to do this on the database level (e.g. some sort of GROUP BY operation).

In JavaScript, you can iterate through the array and create a hash for each record, which should be made up of the fields that you want to be unique. This hash can be then used as a map key, i.e. inserting these record to a map with such key will eliminate the duplicates.

Example:

```
var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var key = data[i].monitor + "#" + data[i].monID + "#" + data[i].manufacturer + ... ;
    map[key] = data[i];
}
```

The `map` object will at the end contain only unique keys mapped to the *last* item with such key.

Note that the `key` is just a string concatenated of the fields you want to be unique. It could not work correctly if your fields contain the character `#`, or if they are *not type string*. If you want to go this way, I would suggest to compute a [hash code from the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript-jquery)

To **identify the duplicates**, you can check in every step of the iteration whether the `key` is already in the map:

```
if (map[key]) {
   // This record is a duplicate
}
```

In order to **group together the duplicate records**, you can construct a map mapping key -> array of duplicates. This could be done like this (showing just the inside of the loop)

```
var key = ...
if (!map[key]) {
    // First time we see this key, let's add it to the map
    map[key] = [ data[i] ]; // Map the key to a new array containing the current record
} else {
    // Duplicate; just add this record to the existing 
    // list of records with the same key
    map[key].push(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: this method works well and is commonly used. Don't forget to adapt it a little if the values in your data can be something else than strings. In case of objects or arrays, you can use `JSON.stringify`. In this case, you should use a hash code as suggested to avoid too long strings

Comment: Can we somehow get rid of these lines (these that i mentioned it expected result) ?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by get rid off these lines...?

Comment: To reject those lines (actually to store them in a log file) who have in common values of keys: monitor, manufacturer, monID, Delivery Way, BarCode Id, Status.

Comment: @AlexBotzis yes, in the line beginning by `var key = data[i].monitor`. You explicitly specify here the fields you will use to compose your key. Just don't put here the fields you want to ignore

Comment: OK I understood this, but after how can i reject those lines based on the key?

Comment: @AlexBotzis if I understand correctly, you want to identify the duplicates... I edited the answer to account for this; just check in every step if the key is already there...

Comment: @emanek I tried to understand your concept and i believe that is correct, but i cannot log the duplicates..Can you help me with that ?? Thank you ...

Comment: @AlexBotzis I extended the answer to show you how to possibly construct list of duplicates, not sure how exactly you want to 'log' them... please accept the answer if it solved your problem, thanks

Comment: Yes it works..Thank you very much for the explanation