# How can I generate unique id's in Vue.js from attributes in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vue-component

I am using Vue.js to generate divs and I would like to use data from a JSON file to do so.

It doesn't necessarily have to be from the JSON but that would be preferable, I just need to create a unique id for each instance of the div in the html below.

What is the best way to create unique ID's for each of the divs?

HTML

```
 <ul>
    <li v-for="(member, index) in cyclists" :key="index" class="col-md-4 inview fromBottomIn" data-in="fromBottomIn" data-out="fromBottomOut">
        <div class="cycling__card">
            <div class="cycling__rider-container">
                <span class="cyclist__name">{{member.name}}</span>
            </div>

            <!-- Need to add id's to the div below -->
            <div id={{member.name}}>
            </div>

        </div>                                      
    </li>
</ul>
```

JSON

```
  "cyclists": [
    {
      "name": "Jason",
      "position": "CEO",
    },
    {
      "name": "Mike",
      "position": "Digital Strategist",
    },
    {
      "name": "Tom",
      "position": "Vice President, Product Management",
    },
    {
      "name": "Jeff",
      "position": "Senior Director, Creative",
    },
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm in this case using [uuid](https://github.com/VitorLuizC/vue-uuid), you will need to merge json data to another object wit new id, so the example:

```
<script>
  import { uuid } from 'vue-uuid'; 

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        uuid: uuid.v1(),
        id: null 
      }
    },
    computed: {
      newCyclists: function () {
       const id = this.id;
       const newID = this.$uuid.v4();
       return {
          ...cyclists,
          id: newID,
        }
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

in `computed` using spread operator to merge new ID with current JSON data with a new ID, `vue-uuid` come from [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) library and v4 is related to generate ID's

Answer (score 6):

There are different approaches.

1. Use an index. You have an array, so just use the index they come from, prepended with something unique to the object. cyclist_1, cyclist_2...
2. Put the ids on the JSON as part of the data.
3. Derive it from the data you have. With a hash, or simply concatenating name + position. Use some function to sanitise it (remove spaces, invalid html characters, etc.)
4. Generate a uuid for each one on the fly. You can use this amazing function for uuid version 4 [developed by the community](https://gist.github.com/jed/982883) to be the shortest possible:

   ```
   function b(a){return a?(a^Math.random()*16>>a/4).toString(16):([1e7]+-1e3+-4e3+-8e3+-1e11).replace(/[018]/g,b)}
   ```

Answer (score 4):

If you didn't want to load in an additional module like `vue-uuid` you could use this function to generate a hash of the result of stringifying each array object on the assumption that each name/position will be unique.

I've used [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616484/1377002) as the basis of this one.

```js
const data = [{"name":"Jason","position":"CEO"},{"name":"Mike","position":"Digital Strategist"},{"name":"Tom","position":"Vice President, Product Management"},{"name":"Jeff","position":"Senior Director, Creative"}];

function genHash(str) {
  var hash = 0, i, chr;
  if (str.length === 0) return hash;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    chr   = str.charCodeAt(i);
    hash  = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr;
    hash |= 0;
  }
  return hash;
};

// For each object in the array create
// a stringyfied version of it and create
// a hash
data.forEach(obj => {
  obj.id = genHash(JSON.stringify(obj));
});

console.log(data);
```

Then you can loop over the data as you would normally.