# Hashing a value in javascript - can it be reversed?

Tags: javascript, hash

I was wondering if the following answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15710692/2527327) regarding hashing can be reversed?

For example if someone got hold of the hashed value, can it be easily reversed?

Comment: no, that is the purpose of a hash

Comment: Depending on what you're using it for, the fastest hash may not be the one you want.

Comment: by definition, a hash is not reversible

Answer (score -1):

what they usually do is they have a list of billions of records of plain text. they will try to hash each of them and compare to the one they got from you. if they found a match, they get the plain text value. 
but it would usually take them years to do so, unless your plain text is something like, '123' or 'pass123'.