# Check if xml is different, either whole xml or just <lastBuildDate>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to verify if a `XML` document got modified after I loaded my page, like maybe every 30 seconds. I obtain the xml by making an `AJAX` request, and preferably, I want to compare the new one and the previous one before calling a function that displays the content into my HTML. How would I do?

```
 $.ajax(url, {
     method: "GET",
     type: 'xml',
     success: function(content){
         // Verify if the new xml content is the same as before, else 
         useContent(content, idContent)
     }
 });
```

What I tried:

```
success: function(content){
    if(previousXML === content) {
        return true;
    } else {
        previousXML = useContent(content, idContent);
    }
}
```

And this is how I return the content of the function `useContent`

```
 function useContent(xmlContent, id){ 
...
return xmlContent}
```

My current attempt which doesn't work:

```
if(previousXML === $thisBuildDate){
                    return true;
                } else {previousXML = useContent(content, idContent);

function useContent(xmlContent, id){
    let $lastBuildDate = $(xmlContent).find('lastBuildDate').text();
  return $lastBuildDate
}
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work since they're equal in my console, but `else {previousXML = useContent(content, idContent);` is still always executed.

Comment: What is the result of your try ? Did it work ? Try hashing the XML strings and checking the hash sum using the algorithm explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript

Comment: The result right now is that it detects that they are not the same xml file and it executes every time the other function.

Comment: Did you think of trying a regex?

Comment: I tried taking the text of the buildDate of the xml document and compare it with the previous one, with no success. `let $thisBuildDate = $(content).find('lastBuildDate').text();`` if(previousXML === $thisBuildDate){
                    return true;
                } else {previousXML = useContent(content, idContent);`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) request-header.

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  type:'xml',
  beforeSend: function(request) {
    request.setRequestHeader('If-Modified-Since', '18:45');
  },
...
```

Comment: How would I set the time to be when the page was loaded? And wouldn't it be `'If-Modified-Since'`