# How to write a Javascipt code to create a hash string of less than or equal to 20 bytes for an input of any string?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, hash

I have multiple strings (containing alphanumeric characters) such as:

- 523d33f0dc94a247536ea849b4834a77
- 12hjh89nd9009idfn90kkui897oiuwer23
- 3284uioen89ji89ji89ddf64f1f167678

And so on.

I want to convert these strings to a hash of less than or equal to 20 bytes. Is there a JS function which can do this?
I am specifically looking for the output to be less than or equal to 20 bytes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a Hash from string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript)

Comment: No capital letters? Or case insensitive? Any length?

Answer (score 1):

Try using :
First install bower (A package manager for web)

```
npm install -g bower
```

Go to the location where the project is located in the terminal and run following command:

```
bower install crypto-js
```

Add the following code in HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to/bower_components/crypto-js/crypto-js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var hash = CryptoJS.MD5("message");// returns 16 bytes hash code
    console.log(hash.toString());
</script>
```

> Here path-to represents the relative path to bower_components folder that was created by the execution of `bower install crypto-js`

Hope this helps. For reference visit https://github.com/brix/crypto-js

Comment: MD5 has been broken for 15 years now.  Cryptographers have been screaming at people to stop using it for anything for over a decade.  Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest instead.

Comment: @btilly Depends on OP's use case. MD5 is [unsuitable for crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15790/why-do-people-still-use-recommend-md5-if-it-has-been-cracked-since-1996) but at the same time [ideal for other purposes](https://idiallo.com/blog/when-to-use-md5), for one and the same reason: it's just so bloody fast.

Comment: @btilly, the OP has not specified anything about crypto needs. Just compression.