# Make sense color for word

Tags: javascript, math, random, colors

We have A-z chars and abcdef0-9 color.

I need get always same color on same word, (apple always red, car always green, cars - always orange) -  even if word have 1 or 3 letter, I wanna see same color every time.
In my function I have random function if no letters to Math color.

Please help me upgrade function and replace Math Random for something like `get letter index in alphabet divide on colors char position` or something else

```
export function MakeSenseColor(str) {
  if(!str && typeof str !== 'string') return '';

  const chars1 = 'abc6789';
  const chars2 = 'abcdef0123456789';

  const Digits = 'qйwцeуrкtеyнuгiшoщpзaхsъdфfыgвhаjпkрlоzлxдcжvэbяnчmсмитьбю1234567890';
  const splittedStr = str.split('').map((s,i,arr) => {
    const charPos = s && (Digits.split('')).indexOf(`${s}`.toLowerCase());

    if(!charPos || charPos === -1) return '0';

    if (charPos >= 0 ) {
      const char = (charPos * chars2.length) / Digits.length
      const charColor = (char * 6) / arr.length;

      return chars2[parseInt(charColor)];
    }

    return '0';
  });

  let color = '#';

  for (let i = 0; color.length < 7; i++) {
    const add = splittedStr[i%6] || chars1.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * chars1.length))

    color = color + add;
  }

  return color;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) the string and use that to generate a hex string indicating the color.  The hash implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52171480/1358308 looks relatively nice to me.

```
// borrowed from https://stackoverflow.com/a/52171480/1358308
function cyrb53(str, seed = 0) {
    let h1 = 0xdeadbeef ^ seed, h2 = 0x41c6ce57 ^ seed;
    for (let i = 0, ch; i < str.length; i++) {
        ch = str.charCodeAt(i);
        h1 = Math.imul(h1 ^ ch, 2654435761);
        h2 = Math.imul(h2 ^ ch, 1597334677);
    }
    h1 = Math.imul(h1 ^ (h1>>>16), 2246822507) ^ Math.imul(h2 ^ (h2>>>13), 3266489909);
    h2 = Math.imul(h2 ^ (h2>>>16), 2246822507) ^ Math.imul(h1 ^ (h1>>>13), 3266489909);
    return 4294967296 * (2097151 & h2) + (h1>>>0);
};

function MakeSenseColor(str) {
    // hash the string and convert to hex
    let hash = cyrb53(str).toString(16);

    // just use the last 6 characters and prepend character to indicate color
    return '#' + hash.slice(-6);
}
```

this gives me unique and consistent results:

- 'apple' = `#002f86`
- 'car' = `#684a21`
- 'cars' = `#c10e83`

these aren't the same colors as you pointed to in your question, but I suppose you could hard code a few that you care about.

Comment: I dont need hardcode, because my words very different. And because this function only for fun/emotions in App.
But, hash from word is what I need. And then I can use hash to convert to color. I think hash.slice give very repeated colors. But this is good answer. Thank you