# Generate same random number based on string parameter

Tags: javascript, math, random, numbers, formula

I'm trying to create a function that will generate the same random number on each execution if the string is the same.

```
function generateRandom(maxInt, stringParam) {
  //generate random based on stringParam
  //output int number from 0 to maxInt
}
```

The goal is to generate the same random number (on different pages) if the stringKey is the same.

```
generateRandom(100, 'abc') // 73
generateRandom(100, 'abc') // 73
generateRandom(100, 'abc') // 73

generateRandom(100, 'qwe') // 45
generateRandom(100, 'qwe') // 45
generateRandom(100, 'qwe') // 45
```

Comment: I imagine you could do some sort of hashing function I guess

Comment: Well it's kind of collision between random and predefined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a Hash from string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Well, that isn't quite 'random' to me.

Comment: Same results for different people whenever `stringParam` is the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really random. I would say this is a kind of encryption. Hopefully, it works for your requirement.

First, get the [Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) from each character in the string. Sum them up and then use `%` ([Remainer operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder)) to round the number to be within `MaxInt` range. This will result in the same number every time you input the same `maxInt` and the same `stringParam`.

```js
function generateRandom(maxInt, stringParam) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < stringParam.length; i++){
    sum += stringParam.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  let result = sum % maxInt;
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

generateRandom(100, 'abc')
generateRandom(100, 'abc')
generateRandom(100, 'abc')

generateRandom(100, 'qwe')
generateRandom(100, 'qwe')
generateRandom(100, 'qwe')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a [`hashing function`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) for this purpose, perhaps a simple one in this case.

Once we have the hash we'll mod with our max output value, e.g. hash % maxInt.

This will give the same output for a given input.

```js
// Simple implementation of a string hashing function (Bernstein)
function hashCode(input) {
    return [...input].reduce((hash, chr) => { 
        return hash * 33 + chr.charCodeAt(0);
    }, 0);
}

function generateRandom(maxInt, stringParam) {
    return hashCode(stringParam) % maxInt;
}

const maxInt = 100;
const inputs = [ 'qwe', 'qwe', 'abc', 'abc', 'def', 'def'];

console.log('In ', 'Out')
inputs.forEach(input => console.log(input, generateRandom(maxInt, input)));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```