# How to avoid memory leaks when adding css to <head>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, memory-management, garbage-collection

So I wrote this vue hook to inject global css programmatically

```js
    const injectedStyles = new Set<string>()
    
    function useGlobalStyles(cssStyles: string) {
        let styleEl: HTMLStyleElement
    
        onBeforeMount(() => {
            if (injectedStyles.has(cssStyles)) {
                return
            } else {
                injectedStyles.add(cssStyles)
            }
    
            styleEl = document.createElement('style')
            styleEl.textContent = cssStyles
            document.head.appendChild(styleEl)
        })
    }
```

It works, but it will keep style tag in head even if component is unmounted. Fixing this is the difficult part for me. I think it would required keeping track of all component instances that depend on these particular `cssStyles`, but then wouldn't it prevent garbage collector from disposing of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is a counter that tracks the number of consumers of a particular style:

1. When a component using this hook mounts:

   - add the style to `<head>`
   - increment the counter
2. When that component unmounts:

   - decrement the counter
   - if the resulting count is zero, remove the style from `<head>`

Note this solution doesn't require tracking component instances, so there's no possibility of a memory leak here.

```js
import { onBeforeMount, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

// map of injected CSS styles and their number of consumers
const injectedStyles = {} as Record<string, number>

function useGlobalStyles(cssStyles: string) {
    let styleEl: HTMLStyleElement

    onBeforeMount(() => {
        if (injectedStyles[cssStyles] === undefined) {
          injectedStyles[cssStyles] = 1
        } else {
          injectedStyles[cssStyles]++

          // style already injected, no need to do anything
          return
        }

        styleEl = document.createElement('style')
        styleEl.textContent = cssStyles
        document.head.appendChild(styleEl)
    })

    onUnmounted(() => {
        injectedStyles[cssStyles]--
        if (injectedStyles[cssStyles] <= 0) {
            delete injectedStyles[cssStyles]
            styleEl?.remove()
            styleEl = undefined
        }
    })
}
```

As a memory optimization, consider storing a hash of the styles in memory instead of the style strings themselves:

```js
import { onBeforeMount, onUnmounted } from 'vue'

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/7616484/6277151
const hashCode = (str: string) => {
    let hash = 0
    if (str.length === 0) return hash
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let chr = str.charCodeAt(i)
        hash = ((hash << 5) - hash) + chr
        hash |= 0 // Convert to 32bit integer
    }
    return hash
}

// map of injected CSS style hashes and their number of consumers
const injectedStyles = {} as Record<string, number>

function useGlobalStyles(cssStyles: string) {
    let styleEl: HTMLStyleElement

    const styleHash = hashCode(cssStyles)

    onBeforeMount(() => {
        if (injectedStyles[styleHash] === undefined) {
          injectedStyles[styleHash] = 1
        } else {
          injectedStyles[styleHash]++

          // style already injected, no need to do anything
          return
        }

        styleEl = document.createElement('style')
        styleEl.textContent = cssStyles
        document.head.appendChild(styleEl)
    })

    onUnmounted(() => {
        injectedStyles[styleHash]--
        if (injectedStyles[styleHash] <= 0) {
            delete injectedStyles[styleHash]
            styleEl?.remove()
            styleEl = undefined
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Yep, that'll do it. Thanks!