# How to hash a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash

I want to hash a string, but I don't want to implement the hashing algorithm.
Is there a built-in JavaScript function or a dependable npm package to hash strings?
If so, how do I use it to hash a string?

For example, if I have

```
const string = "password";
```

I want to run it through some kind of ready-made function or method, like this

```
const hash = hashFunction( string );
```

then get a hash from it, like this

```
console.log( hash ); //5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

NOTE:
I'm aware that this question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616461/generate-a-hash-from-string-in-javascript), but the chosen answer there implements hashing. I'm specifically looking for ready-built dependable functions or methods that hash.

Comment: You want a cryptographic hash? There are libraries like [CryptoJS](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/) that can do that.

Comment: https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-javascript-hashing-libraries?vs=argon2%2Cobject-hash%2Cmd5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe can simply use the built-in object.

It provides cryptographic functionality that includes the ability to hash strings.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const string = "password";
const hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(string).digest('hex'); 

console.log(hash);
```

```
Output: 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

Or as what @Spectric has mentioned, you can use the CryptoJS library.

```
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

const string = "password";
const hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(string).toString();

console.log(hash);
```

```
Output: 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8
```

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: keep in mind, the author hasn't specified if they're looking for a node or browser based solution.

Comment: @PatrykCieszkowski They tagged it [tag:node.js].

Comment: @gre_gor which doesn't say much, since they also tagged it #javascript and #hash. Node is used for compiling client-side apps. They're covering all possibilities.