# Compare 2 one-dimensional arrays for any common values in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, typescript, performance

Suppose I have 2 string arrays from different sources and I want to check if both of them have any values in common, what would be the best approach in Typescript. What would be even better is, if we could find a degree of likeness between them.

Of-course looping through each elements and comparing them individually would work, but I'm looking for a more efficient approach.

- Consider values in array to be unique
- Let's assume they're strings for this example. But even if they're custom objects, they would have an inherent *"compare"* method to check equality.
- Degree of likeness : If all values match then 100% ; if half of the values match 50% . For eg: ["a","b"] and ["a"] would return 50 %. For 100% match, the number of items in both arrays will also have to be same.

*And thanks in advance!!*

Comment: Are elements in the arrays unique? How do you define the "degree of likeness"? Are elements always simple primitive values?

Comment: Yes. Consider the values unique. 
If all values match then 100% ; if half of the values match 50% etc..

Comment: So, what would be the degree of likeness for `["a","b"]` and `["a"]`? 100% or 50%

Comment: 50% I would say, since only half the values match. Let me also edit the question to make these conditions clear. Thanks!!

Comment: See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75581868/intersection-of-2-arrays-containing-objects on how to create the intersection of two arrays. Then you can calculate your likeness based on the size of the original array and the size of the intersection

Comment: If likeness for `['a', 'b']` and `['a']` is 50%, then what is it for `['a', 'b']` and `['a', 'b', 'c']`? 100% or 66.66...%?Is the degree of likeness between `['a', 'b']` and `['a']` the same as the degree of likeness between `['a']` and `['a', 'b']`? Question lacks clarity.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Have edited my question to include more details as per your suggestion. Apologies for any inconvenience. P.S : I'm new to StackOverflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.