# Generate unique id with javascript not exceeding an integer

Tags: javascript

I would like to generate a unique id with javascript without exceeding an integer type.

I see it: [create unique id with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231459/create-unique-id-with-javascript)

With the following solution: `(new Date()).getTime()` but out of the range of an integer.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: What's your "range of integer" here?

Comment: `(pretty much any expression) | 0` will return a value from 0 to 2^32-1. `(expr) >>> 1` will half that range.

Comment: My range for int is: -2147483648 until 2147483647. If possible I prefer using negative values so from -2147483648 to 0.

Comment: Have you read the other answers on that linked post? A running index is very simple, and you can define its range very easily.

Comment: There are no "integers" in JavaScript.

Comment: @Salman: you are right. I mean an integer in a more general sense. To be more precise I use c-sharp integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what size integer you want. Here is a fiddle that shows a couple of ways to do it: http://jsfiddle.net/leemeador/C6YGa/

The idea is to do something like this for a 32 bit integer:

```
var i = new Date().getTime();
i = i & 0xffffffff;
```

Comment: Your solution is very interesting. One question: by using this `0xffff` what is the range? Thanks.

Comment: Each 'F' is 4 bits. FFFF is 16 bits. FFFFFFFF is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to generate unique key (id) with new ES6 Syntax, by returning a Number representing the milliseconds elapsed since the UNIX epoch:

```
export const generateRandomKey = () => Date.now();
```

You can write it in separate file and export. than import to your file using es6 syntax.

```
import {generateRandomKey} from './the/file/path.js';
```