# Associate HTML datalist with input (without setting attributes)

Tags: javascript, html, es6-modules

Using javascript, is it possible to associate a **datalist** with an **input** without setting the **id** and **list** attributes to a string?

The HTML5 **datalist** element is typically (and maybe exclusively) associated with an **input** element by setting the input's **list** attribute to the **id** attribute of the **datalist**:

```
<input list="animals">
<datalist id="animals">
  <option value="Bear">
  <option value="Cat">
  <option value="Dog">
</datalist>
```

These attributes would be unnecessary if the input element could encapsulate the datalist with a closing  tag:

```
<input>
    <datalist>
      <option value="Bear">
      <option value="Cat">
      <option value="Dog">
    </datalist> 
</input>
```

However, this does not produce auto-suggestions like the previous markup does.

Let's say you want to create an ecmascript module that exports a div containing an input that has a datalist. Furthermore, let's also assume that this module will be consumed by numerous websites on the internet.

Exporting this div, already containing **id** and **list** attributes, could cause a naming conflict on that webmaster's website.

Other than using an obscure naming convention for the **id**, is there a way of exporting this module in a manner that makes it impossible to cause naming conflicts with all sites on the internet?

Comment: The spec for the input element says about the list attribute that "The value must be the id of a <datalist> element in the same document." So I don't think there is another way than using id.

Comment: As @ecg8 says [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-datalist-element) doesn't list any other possibility. Best you can do is generate an ID in JS that's as unique as possible, reducing collision probability. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231459/create-unique-id-with-javascript) has some ways to do that.

Comment: It is too bad the input cannot encapsulate the datalist. And, it is also too bad that the datalist cannot be binded directly to the input at the Javascript-DOM level without having to id anything. Thanks guys.