# I want to give an id to every todo element that renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    setNewItem(event.target.value)
}
```

In this function, I want to give every todo element a new and unique id.

```
function addTodo(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    setNewItem({ id: 0 })
    setTodosList(prevList => [...prevList, newItem])
    setNewItem("");
    inputRef.current.focus()
    if (newItem === "") {
        alert("Plese Write an todo");
    }
}

function removeTodo() {
    // setTodosList(prevItems => prevItems.filter(item => item.id !== id))
}

const allTodos = todosList.map(item => (
    <li key={item}>
        {item}
        <i className="ri-delete-bin-line del" onClick={removeTodo}></i>
    </li>
));
```

Here all my code is running.

```
<header>
    <img src={require('./images/todo.png')} alt="Todo-Logo" width="100" height="100" />
    <h1 className="title">My Todo App</h1>
</header>
<div className="container">
    <br />
    <form>
        <div className="input-btnFlex">
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Write Your Todo "
                name="newItem"
                ref={inputRef}
                value={newItem}
                onChange={handleChange}
            />
            <button className="ri-add-circle-fill add-btn" onClick={addTodo}></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
        <ul>
            {allTodos}
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [create unique id with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231459/create-unique-id-with-javascript) see also https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+javascript+generate+unique+id

Comment: If you are not persisting the todos in localstorage you can use the following: `const createId = ((id) => () => id++)(1);const id = createId()`

Comment: Why do you want to add the IDs? What will you be using them for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can time stamp

If a real human user is creating todo's one after another you can use a timestamp as an identifier since it will always be different each time and will stay the same no matter the order.

- Always unique
- Hard to guess
- Always sequential

```
setNewItem({ id: Date.now().toString() })
```

Answer (score 1):

create a local variable  id and every time you need a new id just increment the id..
Otherwise i would recommend **assign Date.now() as the id** as it will never have a duplicate value

Other Method **[Not Recommended] only use this if absolutely necessary**:
if you are using a list use the index of list as id..

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options that can be used for ids:

- Date/Time Stamp.
- Any unique id generator for javascript like UUID
- Create your own random id generator function using Math.random()
- You can create your own custom id string using index