# V-model doesn't work when using Bootstrap Tokenfield

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-tokenfield

I create dynamic component using Vue and Bootstrap Tokenfield. But `v-model` doesn't work in this case.

Assume, I have an array below:

**index   variant_options**
1       aaa
2       sss

When I remove index 1, the result of index 1 should be "sss" but still "aaa"

```
<div class="card" v-for="(variant, index) in form.variants" :key="index">
<div class="card-body"> <span class="float-right" style="cursor: pointer" @click="deleteVariant(index)">
                                                            X
                                                        </span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <label for="weight">Variant Type {{ index + 1 }} </label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="variant_type" class="form-control" v-model="
                                                                            variant.variant_type
                                                                        " @keyup="tokenField()" placeholder="Input variant type. E.g: Color" name="name" required autofocus /> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label for="weight">Variant Options {{ index + 1 }}</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="variant_options" autofocus="true" v-model="
                                                                            variant.variant_options
                                                                        " @mouseover="
                                                                            tokenField()
                                                                        " placeholder="Input variant options. E.g: Blue, Brown," class="
                                                                            form-control
                                                                            variant_options
                                                                        " /> </div>
data() {
    return {
        form: new Form({
            variants: [
                {
                    variant_type: '',
                    variant_options: '',
                },
            ],
        }),
    };
},
methods: {
    tokenField() {
        $('.variant_options').tokenfield({
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true,
        });
    },
    addVariant() {
        if (this.form.variants.length <= 1) {
            this.form.variants.push({
                variant_type: '',
                variant_options: '',
            });
        } else {
            this.error = 'You can only add 2 type of varians';
            $('#errMsg').show();
        }
    },
    deleteVariant(index) {
        this.form.variants.splice(index, 1);
        $('#errMsg').hide();
    },
}, // methods:
```

Comment: @CheerUp Your code is incomplete. Please provide the full code.

Comment: Is there any reason for the `new Form({` bit in the `data()` code?

Comment: @Fabalance: What do you mean incomplete? What part do you need? What is missing part? Just tell me. I think, I've write all of code.

Comment: @JoséA.Zapata: I use v`-form` to binding data. https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform

Comment: @CheerUp Just provide the full code of your component. `<script>` is missing, `<template>` is missing and you `html` tags don´t close correctly.

Comment: @Fabalance: That's nothing to do with `<script> <html> or <template>`. If you understand the problem, you won't request to provide the rest of code. The problem itself only related to `v-model`. That's it!

Comment: @CheerUp The point of providing the rest of the code is to have a reproducible example to test. If you don't give that, it's harder to pinpoint the exact issue. And word of advice: check the attitude, you won't get much help if you act like that.

Comment: The reason I dont include the common code like `<template> <script>` because it's familiar.Everyone knows where to put this even if he's new to Vue.

Comment: I think you need to assign form again, by creating a new Form and using the new variants array.

Comment: @CheerUp As José stated, we need it to have a reproducible example. It doesn´t matter, if we know, where these tags belong. We need to know, if you done it right. Just try to reproduce your code, it will not work. You provided an empty array and have unclosed `html`.

Comment: @Fabalance: If you need more clear, kindly refer to this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Efr7SUrBUQw 
Thanks!

Comment: @Fabalance: Do you mean I should write it in jsfiddle?

Comment: @CheerUp You have a similar option for a snippet on SO. If you want to do it in JSFiddle, you can. Just add the link afterwards and I will take a look at it.

Comment: The problem has been solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When rendering list using `v-for` **do not use** `index` variable from `v-for` as `:key`, especially not when loop content contains any `<input>` element and/or you are adding/removing/sorting items...

See the docs - [Maintaining State](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

Note that the docs does not mention or discourage using `index` variable as `:key` in any way. But if you think about it, using `index` is indeed same as not using `:key` at all. Because role of `:key` is to establish relationship (identity) between each item used in the loop and the DOM that is generated for it. This is something `index` can't do...

`key` should be stable (not change over time) and unique over all the items in the list. Sometime the data already contain such item (for example when the data comes from server/database). If there is no data property with above mentioned features (as in your case where both `variant_type` and `variant_options` are editable by the user), just generate your own artificial key. There are [multiple ways to generate unique id in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3231459/381282)

Example using "running index":

```js
data() {
    return {
        nextId: 1,
        form: new Form({
            variants: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    variant_type: '',
                    variant_options: '',
                },
            ],
        }),
    };
},
methods: {
    addVariant() {
        if (this.form.variants.length <= 1) {
            this.form.variants.push({
                id: this.nextId++,
                variant_type: '',
                variant_options: '',
            });
        } else {
            this.error = 'You can only add 2 type of varians';
            $('#errMsg').show();
        }
    },
}
```

...and use `:key="variant.id"` in the template

Comment: So, what is the solution? Could you please solve this problem with code? I've stuck on this problem many days.

Comment: Yo man, it's working. Thank you very much. You've made my day lighter. Still trying to understand how it's work.