# is there a way to generate a unique id of type number? how to safely fix this duplication problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i have question please, there is an old code where they  manually made a function to randomly generate an id, the id type is a number and not a string. since it not that safe
they lately found a duplicate id.
What's the best and safest solution to fix this, i thought of using UUID to generate an id but uuid only generate strings while it's a number? if i change the id type to string would it cause a problem with old records?

Ps: they used Express.js and mongoose

Comment: Can you please send us a link to their code or paste it in your question

Comment: I can't share the code, sorry. But if you have other questions I'm ready to answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create unique IDs with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231459/how-can-i-create-unique-ids-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

[How can I create unique IDs with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231459/how-can-i-create-unique-ids-with-javascript)
You can try methods in this to replace the function. Choose one which fits you profile and needs the best.

Comment: I can use UUID or objectId but the problem is that it has to always be a number

Comment: Try something like this ?
```
const uid = function(){
    return Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2);
```
Convert the string in the above one to a number ?

Answer (score 0):

browser/js runtimes like node evolve and now you don't need any libraries to generate save IDs.

All it takes is `crypto.randomUUID()`

```js
document.querySelector('#output').innerText = crypto.randomUUID();
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```