# Is there a way to create a php-like unique id using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Unique id created by php - `uniqid()` - for example - `63afe4f2903a2` - perfectly suits my needs, although it is not perfectly assured to be unique.

So I need a `13` characters length ID which is made using the same logic as `uniqid` in php

Is there a way to create it using plain javascript or jquery ?
Thanks.

**update**

There is no answer on my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231459)

Comment: You can use this for generating the uniqueID by javascript or jquery like that Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);

Comment: _There is no answer on my question here_ Ok, so how many unique IDs you wish to have per request? Are these IDs for div tags or something else? I don't see how none of the answers there answer your question!

Comment: @nice_dev - As I said - I simply want an id - as I got it using php. So - one ID - per request. What for I will use it - that's absolutelly irrelevant here. And you should see very easily that - there is no answer on the given link.

Comment: @provance Ok, so it's one ID per request. _What for I will use it - that's absolutely irrelevant here_ It is been asked because if the ID is handling something critical, it needs to be cryptographically secure and not just unique.  Many answers give you a way to get only one unique ID per request. See this fiddle https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3ytgmyew7

Comment: @nice_dev - As I said - `it perfectly suits my needs, although it is not perfectly assured to be unique`. So - once again - `it perfectly suits my needs, although it is not perfectly assured to be unique`. I hope that's enough now

Comment: @SajidIjaz - your code produce an id of `9` characters. How to get `13` characters as in php,, pls ?

Comment: The "perfectly assured to be unique" is *also* in one click from Google. So I did it for you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense - excuse me - can't understand your comment. What about one click on Google and what did you do for me ?

Comment: @provance _although it is not perfectly assured to be unique_ So are you proposing that current time since epoch is not guaranteed to be unique? Your requirement doesn't even need the time to be at micro or nanosecond level.

Comment: @nice_dev - I do not propose anything You should go to php manual. Or simply type `php uniqid` in google.

Comment: @provance Well, we were discussing about javascript solution, weren't we? I even shared the fiddle for the same. Anyways, good luck!

Comment: @nice_dev - thanks, but I don't need a discuss. I need the solution.

Comment: You got shown many solutions,  including a live demo, above. If it doesn't help, explain precisely why